# Spring batch - data is not processed completely before reading next page from DB

Tags: spring, out-of-memory, spring-batch

I have a table `MY_TABLE` which contains about 500k rows, the reader is supposed to read from this table with `pageSize` as 100, then it should process this page as my processor and write on DB as per my writer.

What is happening is, the reader is keep on reading in 100,100 pages till exhausted and giving `OutOfMemoryError` at like 400k records.

I'm not sure why this is not working in pages and `chunk` at all, and why it's reading all the data from table instead of only working with `pageSize` amount.

Below is the code which I have for `step` and `reader`.

````
    public Step customStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<CustomEntityClass> reader,
        ItemProcessor<CustomEntityClass, List<CustomEntityClassSecond>> processor, ItemWriter<List<CustomEntityClassSecond>> writer)
    {
        DefaultResultCompletionPolicy comp = new DefaultResultCompletionPolicy();

        return stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.STEP_NAME)
            .<CustomEntityClass, List<CustomEntityClassSecond>> chunk(comp)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step purgeTasklet(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, Tasklet tasklet)
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.TASKLET_NAME).tasklet(tasklet).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<CustomEntityClass> customReader(@Qualifier(DATA_SOURCE) DataSource dataSource)
        throws Exception
    {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<CustomEntityClass> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean pagingQueryFactoryBean = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        pagingQueryFactoryBean.setSelectClause("*");
        pagingQueryFactoryBean.setFromClause("MY_TABLE");
        pagingQueryFactoryBean.setWhereClause("CREATIONDATE <= :creationDate");
        pagingQueryFactoryBean.setSortKey("id");
        pagingQueryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setQueryProvider(pagingQueryFactoryBean.getObject());
        reader.setPageSize(100);
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(CustomEntityClass.class));

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(BatchConstants.CREATION_DATE_FORMAT);
        String creationDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("creationDate", creationDate);
        reader.setParameterValues(parameters);
        return reader;
    }```
````

Comment: Can this class be a issue here to use in chunk?
```DefaultResultCompletionPolicy comp = new DefaultResultCompletionPolicy();```

Should I go with SimpleCompletionPolicy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunk size that Spring Batch uses is independent of the page size in the reader. It makes sense to set them consistently, but this not strictly required.

It should work as expected with

```
stepBuilderFactory.get(BatchConstants.STEP_NAME)
        .<CustomEntityClass, List<CustomEntityClassSecond>>chunk(100)
        .reader(reader)
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(writer).build();
```

Then Spring Batch will use 100 items per chunk which is exactly the content of one queried page.

Comment: can you tell me why you used int chunk size, instead of say "new SimpleCompletionPolicy(100)" ?

Comment: It's equivalent. If you pass an int chunk size, Spring Batch will create the policy for you. It's a matter of taste, but I'd prefer passing the int as it makes the application code a bit leaner.